# change background color of createMaterialTopTabNavigator screens

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator

I need to change all of the tabNavigators screen background color

```
 <Tab.Navigator
  tabBarOptions={{
    style: {
      display: 'none',
    },
  }}>
  <Tab.Screen name="screen" component={screen} />
  <Tab.Screen name="screen2" component={screen2} />
  <Tab.Screen name="screen3" component={screen3} />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

How can i change the background color of every screen?

Comment: You will have to set the style in each individual component for `screen1`, `screen2` .etc

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer!

```
 <Tab.Navigator
  sceneContainerStyle={{
    backgroundColor: theme['primaryColor'],
  }}
 >
```

for createMaterialTopTabNavigation you have to use sceneContainerStyle and apply it to the wrapper and it will add it to each screen :)